# Unknown option: .presents, Entrypoint undefined = index.html, import is not working in the index.js file

Tags: npm, webpack

**I have been tried many kinds of way **[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8FJi.png)

-npm uninstall and install

-rm package-lock.json yarn lock

-rm package-lock.json yarn lock

-npm uninstall babel-loader --save-dev and install

-changed .babelrc file

but that was not working  please help me if you have this solution

version webpack 4.41.4, windows 10

[error png 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8FJi.png)

[error png 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPOJ7.png)

[error png 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTjCx.png)

[Package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG72z.png)

[Webpack.config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5y7B.png)

[.babelrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT9E3.png)

[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBWQI.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create [mcve] if possible

Answer (score 0):

I could have solved this problem.

solution

- deleted the presents 
  [webpack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaBtp.png)

but one more problem is left

problem

- import is not working in my index.js file 
  [index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfUHt.png)